# How to make place UIView and UITableView similar to Spotify's playlists

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiview

I want to create a view controller with a UIView on the top and a UITableView on the bottom. I have tried to use a panGestureRecognizer on the tableView to drag the table all the way up to the top of the screen, but I have no idea how to transfer the touch from the UIView to the scrollView of the tableView. How would I go about implementing this viewController?

[image: First]

[image: Second]
[image: Third]

Comment: I have the same question